# Pyglet slower on a faster computer

Tags: python, hardware, pyglet

I changed my computer recently, and the very same program using Python and Pyglet runs a lot slower on the newer computer than on the old one (25 seconds vs. 10 seconds).

The older was an Asus EEE 1015p, with the following specs :

- processor : Intel Atom N570
- memory : 2 Gb
- gfx : Intel GMA 3150
- OS : Windows 7 Starter Edition 32
- python version : 2.7
- pyglet version : 1.1.4

The newer is a HP Pavilion dm1 :

- processor : Processeur   AMD E2-1800 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics, 1700 MHz
- gfx : AMD Radeon HD 7340 Graphics
- memory : 4 Gb
- OS : Windows 8 64
- python version : 2.7 (32 bits)
- pyglet version : 1.2alpha1

I suspected a problem of graphics driver, but some programs using OpenGL (for example, Playstation2 Emulator PCSX2) run clearly faster on the newer (by around 40 %) so I'm quite surprised. So I wonder if speed issues are known for some pyglet versions.

The program use batches to render a map made of 4 tiled layers, on which sprites are moving.

Thanks to anyone who can point me what is wrong...

Comment: Any link to the source of that program?

Comment: The program consists of several modules, is quite long and complicated (I'm currently rewriting it) and I didn't have time to make it shorter and easier. But my question was not to optimize it (not yet :) ) but just to know why it's slower on a more powerful machine. 

I can provide infos about it if really needed, or even upload the source code somewhere, but I didn't want to bother people with unclean code...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I give the answer in the unlikely case someone would encounter it :

it was a driver settings issue : in AMD Vision Engine Control Center, I had to move performance vs. quality setting to max. performance. I have now similar performances on the 2 machines.